# Finding a max from a known list of variables WITHOUT using arrays

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int box1 = 30;
int box2 = 99;
int box3 = 140;
int box4 = 200;
int box5 = 220;
int box6 = 260;
int box7 = 300;
int box8 = 310;
int box9 = 500;
int box10 = 100;

return(0);
}
```

I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
string var;
int i = 1;

for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
var = "box" + std::to_string(i);
cout << var << endl;
}
```

but it kept telling me that std::to_string was an ambiguous call to an overloaded function. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: “without using arrays” is such an unusual restriction that I would need to know why you have it before I would answer such a question.

Comment: Are you using VS2010 (or maybe it was VS2012)? One of those lacked all the overloads that `std::to_string` is supposed to have, leading to ambiguities. `std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(i))` should work. It looks like you're trying to create the variable names, what are you planning on doing with those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you asked* ([proof that it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a27f1f5f936fab80), [preprocessed (scroll down for output)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/782e372237f85b39)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define VAR_N(z, n, nameBase) BOOST_PP_CAT(nameBase, BOOST_PP_INC(n))

int main() {
    int box1 = 30;
    int box2 = 99;
    int box3 = 140;
    int box4 = 200;
    int box5 = 220;
    int box6 = 260;
    int box7 = 300;
    int box8 = 310;
    int box9 = 500;
    int box10 = 100;

    std::cout << std::max({BOOST_PP_ENUM(10, VAR_N, box)}); //500
}
```

---

*Seriously, don't have ten variables whose names only differ by successive numbers. That's what arrays are for.

Comment: This is a correct answer. However, helping the asker to pursue his moronic approach isn't exactly noble, is it?

Comment: @Columbo, No, it's not really intended to be used. I have no idea why it's come down to ten similar, but separate variables, but I sincerely hope that changes.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you didn't prohibit using an array, I'd probably prefer a `vector` to an array anyway.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> boxes{30, 99, 140, 200, 220, 260, 300, 310, 500, 100};
    std::cout << *std::max_element(boxes.begin(), boxes.end());
}
```

Seems straightforward enough.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're deconstructing the question so delightfully:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97662983939915c2)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::max({ 30, 99, 140, 200, 220, 260, 300, 310, 500, 100});
}
```

Not using arrays, not even as part of the implementation of a vector or similar

Answer (score 0):

This solution finds your maximum without using any arrays or data structures whatsoever.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << 500;
}
```

Comment: I'd posit that "human brain" structures data, and comprises a large array of neurons. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find max then you can do it like this:

Example code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;


void Max() {
}

int max_val=0;;

template<typename T , typename ... type_pack>
int Max(T x, const type_pack... rest) {

    max_val=(max_val>x)?max_val:x;
    Max(rest...);
    return max_val;
}

int main()
{   
int box1 = 30;
int box2 = 99;
int box3 = 140;
int box4 = 200;
int box5 = 220;
int box6 = 260;
int box7 = 300;
int box8 = 310;
int box9 = 500;
int box10 = 100;

std::cout<<Max(box1,box2,box3,box4,box5,box6,box7,box8,box9,box10);

return(0);
}
```

You can pass all the variables as argument to the function `Max()` (the number of argument is not fixed) and it will return the Max for you...
without using array or any loop (It uses recursion).